# Chrome developer timeline tool graph

Tags: web-applications, graph, google-chrome-devtools, timeline

I am using the Chrome developer Timeline tool to monitor the performance of my web application. I also want to present the results in a table or graph but I can't see any way of doing this?? Is there an option to export the data into a graph or table somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can export the raw timeline data with <kbd>Ctrl+S</kbd> and then plot anything you like.

Comment: Thanks I wasn't even looking for something as detailed as that just something like the graph it shows displaying the results. But I ended up just making my own table, thanks anyway though.